# ffmpeg: how to convert libaom-av1 to whatsapp format

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a video which has video format of `libaom-av1` format and `opus` audio format

[image]

I convert it into mp4 using

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mkv -c copy -c:a aac 1.mp4
```

now `1.mp4` is of size `2.4 mb`

But when i try to share it on `whatsapp`, it shows as `9.4 MB`

[image]

Now i want to keep the same size around 1.5-2MB and share in `whatsapp` with `same quality`

I also tried

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mkv \
  -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -preset medium -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 48k \
  -movflags faststart \
  1.mp4
```

but the quality is very poor

how` can i do

the original video (`test.mkv`) can be obtained at https://0x0.st/-Ad4.mp4

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatsapp, but if it's like the majority of social media apps then it will re-encode whatever you give it. You should verify if this is the behavior of whatsapp. If it is there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand what libaom-av1 actually is.

It's an extremely efficient codec. Roughly 3 times as efficient as libx264 which WhatsApp uses. So without compromising quality you need to have at least a 3times larger file in WhatsApp, even more if the AV1 file has a noise model. Even H265 is way less efficient than AV1, around 30-40% less depending on whether the AV1 file was encoded with film grain or not.

There's nothing you can do. WhatsApp decides to use ancient H264 as their video codec. You cannot change that. 9MB with x264 for a 2.4MB AV1 file seems totally reasonable.

Offtopic:

If you want to try AV1 by yourself here's a command to encode any video to AV1 using the official production encoder libsvtav1, be aware that this will take quite some time (preset 6 is a fast preset, go to preset 4 if you want an even smaller file which however will take longer, preset 8 is only 10% more efficient than x265 medium but at the same extremely fast speed):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libsvtav1 -acodec copy -qp 23 -preset 6 -g 300 output.mkv
```

-g 300 tells the encoder to place a keyframe after 300 frames, change that accordingly to your framerate*5.

You can also use the reference encoder libaom-av1, however that one is not only way slower than svt while being not more efficient, but also isn't really able to multithread. In this case it is even less efficient than the svt command above but is way slower. You can try it ofc:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libaom-av1 -cpu-used 6 -acodec copy -crf 23 output.mkv
```